PHPSpeadsheet: Import XLSX file with formatted cell
I tried to import and excel file with formatted text (color, hyperlink, bold...) but can't import the format. I've searched around but cannot find anything related. Here's the screenshot of an example cell i need to import: formatted cell
Is there any way to import the file and keep the format?
Would be great if anyone can help!
Thank you!
Below are my code for the import:
    $inputFile = 'uploads/importexcel/news.xlsx';
    try{
        $inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
        $objReader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
            die('Error');
    }
    
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    
    for( $row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);
        
        if($row == 2)
        {
            continue;
        }
        $sku = New Financenews();   
        $sku->employee_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->employee_id;
        $sku->credit_type = $rowData[0][1];
        $sku->ticket_number = $rowData[0][2];
        $sku->update_from_IH = $rowData[0][3];
        $sku->IH_instruction = $rowData[0][4];
        $sku->intructrion_81 = $rowData[0][5];
        $sku->uid = $rowData[0][7];
        $date_formated = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($rowData[0][0])->format('Y-m-d');
        $sku->date_update = $date_formated;
        
        $sku->save();   
        
    }
    echo "Done Import";`


Does this answer your question? PHPSpreadsheet read styles from text in a cell

I've tried this but it said Call to a member function getRichTextElements() on string. Not sure if this $rowData[0][4]->getRichTextElements() is correct or I need to do something else.
